# Move .android and .gradle file from folder C: to folder D:

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, gradle

Is there any way to move .android and .gradle folder from folder C: to folder D:? Both file takes a lot of memory in folder C:

If there is a safe way to move it, I hope you can answer my question. Thank you!!!

I already try to move Android/Sdk folder from folder C: to folder D: and it's safe. I can use my Android Studio as usual. But, in this case, I want to know is there any way to move .android and .gradle folder? Because it really takes a lot memory on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

You can move the folders and create a soft-link at the old position in file-system that points to the new directory. The only requirement is that C: and D: do use NTFS file-system.

1. Make sure there are no Java gradle daemon process running (this could prevent you from moving the `.gradle` folder. Or you simple reboot Windows.
2. Move the complete directory to the new location, e.g. `.gradle` to `D:\Android\.gradle`.
3. Execute `mklink /D D:\Android\.gradle C:\Users\%username%\.gradle`

Afterwards you should see a `.gradle` folder in your user home directory that shows the content of the folder located on the D: drive.

If your have a fast and not volume limited internet connection you can simply delete `.gradle` folder in step 2 instead of moving it. Then create an empty `.gradle` folder on D: drive. Next time you compile an Android Studio project gradle will automatically download everything that is required.